# How do I avoid rosbag's messages and disk space checks?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently when running rosbag record I periodically get this warning message:

> Less than 5GB of space free on disk
> with
> /tmp/_2011-07-18-14-36-18_12.bag.active.

Every 20 seconds. Despite being annoying, what bothers me is that browsing the code I've seen that when there's less than 1GB the recording is stopped. http://www.ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/rosrecord/html/c++/recorder_8cpp_source.html

I understand the risks but I want to keep recording even below 1GB and disable those annoying logs every 20seconds.

Is there any way to do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10625/how-do-i-avoid-rosbag%27s-messages-and-disk-space-checks?/) by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Decrease the number of bytes to what you want or just make them 0 , in these two line:

from:

00109         if (free_space < 1073741824ull)

to:

00109         if (free_space < 0000000000ull)

from:

00115         else if (free_space < 5368709120ull)

to:

00115         else if (free_space < 0000000000ull)

and then do :

```
rosmake rosrecord
```

---

Originally posted by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) with karma: 175 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-07-21**:
@rajat, none of the other options to rosbag record are implemented as ROS parameters; they are all command line options. Why would this be any different? Also I have to take back what I said about Electric; it's already in feature freeze.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-07-20**:
Thanks I'll try to do it.

**Comment by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on 2011-07-19**:
You should make it as a ros parameter and then submit the patch, The parameters by default should have the values which are present in the source code . but we can change the value by changing the parameter .

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-07-19**:
Unless there's a way (outside ROS) to spoof the disk space on a drive then it seems that there's no other way but to change the source. If I were you I'd file an enhancement ticket. If you attach a working patch then maybe you could get it squeaked into Electric (next ROS release in August).

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2011-07-19**:
Yeah, I could do that, as well as remove the call to this method or make it return without checking anything. But the thing is if there's a solution that doesn't involve modifying the source code, otherwise each time we (as a company) upgrade ROS version, we have to change it and recompile.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2016-03-02**:
Did this ever get implemented as a parameter or command line option?  I want to record locally onboard my robot, even though my robot has less than 1 Gig of free disk space.  Thanks.

**Comment by [Ben Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/28372/ben-cole/) on 2016-10-28**:
I second Kurt. It would really make sense if this were configurable so I could also record locally on my small robot that doesn't have a lot of space.